# PushPageModel not working on simple button in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, freshmvvm

Using the function below does not move the page to the desired view.  The function is called from a Button Command

```
WeeklyJourneysCommand = new AsyncCommand(WeeklyJourneysAsync);
```

Which calls

```
 async Task WeeklyJourneysAsync()
        {
           await base.CoreMethods.PushPageModel<EventListPageModel>(App.CurrentWeekNumber);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted  - multiple master detail pages causing issues